# JSQMessagesController textview stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

My TextView is freezing after sending 2-3 messages. My iOS version is 10.2.1 and testing device is iPhone 6Plus, JSQMessagesViewController version is 7.3.4 and the code is in Obj-C. I have implemented the following method :

```
-(void)didPressSendButton:(UIButton *)button withMessageText:(NSString *)text senderId:(NSString *)senderId senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName date:(NSDate *)date
{
    [self addMessagewithId:senderId name:senderDisplayName date:date andText:text inArray:_messages inGroup:nil];

    NSDateFormatter *dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateF.dateFormat= @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzzz";
    NSString *dateStr = [dateF stringFromDate:date];

    NSDictionary *mdata = @{@"text": text, @"senderId":senderId, @"displayName": senderDisplayName, @"date":dateStr};

    // Push data to Firebase Database
    [[[_rootRef child:@"messages"] childByAutoId] setValue:mdata];

    [self finishSendingMessageAnimated:NO];

    _isTyping =false;
    [self sendIsTyping];    
}

-(void)addMessagewithId:(NSString*) senderId name:(NSString*) name date:(NSDate*)date andText:(NSString*) text inArray:(NSMutableArray*)array inGroup:(dispatch_group_t)group1
{

    JSQMessage* message = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:senderId senderDisplayName:name date:date text:text];

    [array addObject:message];

    if (group1) {
        dispatch_group_leave(group1);
    }

}
```

But after calling

`[self finishSendingMessageAnimated:NO];`

the textview starts freezing and the cursor stays where the text ends. This freezing time increases as user sends more messages. Please help.

Comment: There is not much we can do with the information you have provided. Could you give us a bigger sample of your code. It sounds like you may have an issue with sending larger amounts of data every time you send a message but that is a guess based on the code you have provided. If you could give us more that would help.

Comment: @DanielLeonard I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: So I would first check and see if it is firebase that is slowing you down. Just comment out `[[[_rootRef child:@"messages"] childByAutoId] setValue:mdata];` and send a couple of messages. If there is no slow down of hanging then your issue is firebase not the library. let me know if that dose not remove the delay.

Comment: @DanielLeonard Your solution helped me. For those who are having same issue, please go through following link:
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my code was that after calling the method

```
[[[_rootRef child:@"messages"] childByAutoId] setValue:mdata];

it was again reloading all the collectionview as expected from FIRDataEventTypeValue . So I put an array like this :

 [[[_rootRef child:@"messages"] queryOrderedByKey] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
for (FIRDataSnapshot *child in snapshot.children) {

                    if ([_arrSnap containsObject:child.key]) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [_arrSnap addObject:child.key];

                        //do rest of your coding here
                    }
}
}
```

so the reloading stopped for my collectionview and all the extra execution of code stopped.

Also thanks to @danielleonard for his reply. It led me to this solution.